# Unable to read Parquet file with Spark, java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet

I am trying to read parquet files from S3 with Spark. I tried both using Hive table or directly reading from S3.
Here is the stacktrace:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 83.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 83.0 (TID 17419, ip-10-23-0-40.ec2.internal, executor 82): org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Encounter error while reading parquet files. One possible cause: Parquet column cannot be converted in the corresponding files. Details:
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 1 in block 0 in file s3://path_to_my_file.snappy.parquet
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:251)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:214)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableLong.update(SpecificInternalRow.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SpecificInternalRow.update(SpecificInternalRow.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRowConverter$RowUpdater.set(ParquetRowConverter.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetPrimitiveConverter.addBinary(ParquetRowConverter.scala:90)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl$2$6.writeValue(ColumnReaderImpl.java:317)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.writeCurrentValueToConverter(ColumnReaderImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.RecordReaderImplementation.read(RecordReaderImplementation.java:406)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:226)
    ... 26 more

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2041)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2029)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2262)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2211)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2200)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:777)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:401)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:751)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:710)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:719)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Encounter error while reading parquet files. One possible cause: Parquet column cannot be converted in the corresponding files. Details:
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:226)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:130)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:291)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:283)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
  ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 1 in block 0 in file s3://path_to_my_file.snappy.parquet
  at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:251)
  at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:207)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:130)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:214)
  ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
  at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableLong.update(SpecificInternalRow.scala:148)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SpecificInternalRow.update(SpecificInternalRow.scala:228)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRowConverter$RowUpdater.set(ParquetRowConverter.scala:164)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetPrimitiveConverter.addBinary(ParquetRowConverter.scala:90)
  at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl$2$6.writeValue(ColumnReaderImpl.java:317)
  at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.writeCurrentValueToConverter(ColumnReaderImpl.java:367)
  at org.apache.parquet.io.RecordReaderImplementation.read(RecordReaderImplementation.java:406)
  at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:226)
  ... 26 more
```

The strange thing when I read whole bucket with all partitions the error appears, but when I try to read just the file which resulted the issue, it is fine. The column has `Long` type. When I drop that column, everything works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check what `spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema` conf. is set to?

Comment: @mazaneicha It is set to false

Comment: @mazaneicha but setting it to true did not help

Comment: How was the data written? What if you set `spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet` to false?

Comment: It seems to work when I provide schema, thought I tried that  too, but maybe I didn't. So it is written as String but for some reason Spark detect field as long,because field changed at some point.

Comment: However, now I get following exception `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainLongDictionary`

Comment: Ok, now it becomes clear. So, last exception is because in another file that field is `int64`. I guess the goal is to convert them to either string or long.